# CSS will not align where i need it

Tags: html, css

so ive got my code and theese color bubbles things wont align to the toolbar ive included all the code. apart from the javascript as i do not think it is needed.

Its a simple drawing application and i need theese "color bubbles" to be up on the tool bar
and they are kind of hanging down.
Please help me!

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <html>
  <head>
       <title>Project - Draw</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="drawstyle.css">
  </head>

  <body style='margin:0'>
    <div id="toolbox">
    <div id="rs">
       Radius <span id="rsvalue">10</span>
       <div id="decrs" class="rscontrol">-</div>
       <div id="incrs" class="rscontrol">+</div>
    </div>
      <div id="colors">
        <div class="swatch active"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;">
    Your browser dose not support this application. Get Chrome!!! :(
   </canvas>
    <script src="draw.js"></script>
    <script src="radius.js"></script>
  </body>
```

** CSS CODE:**

```
        *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;

    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
         }

        #toolbox {
       width: 100%;
       height: 50px;
       padding: 10px;
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       background-color: #2B2B2B;
       color: #D4D4D4;
        }

        .rscontrol {
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       background-color: #9E9E9E;
       display: inline-block;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 5px;
        }

       #rscontrol {
      float: left;
       }

       #colors {
      float: right;
      }

       .swatch {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0px 2px 2px
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 10px;
      }
```

I know its not all aligned properly ^CSS^ but it is in my version i just have to do 8 spaces to get it to show up as 'code'.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIZXe.png). They are there in the top right. And you can also [see a live version here](http://dibjso.tk/projects/draw.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `float: left` to `rs` div, like this:

```
#rs{
    float: left;
}
```

**Example on fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SWRaA/

Comment: damn, 10 seconds earlier :(

Comment: :D sometimes being quick is not bad, IYKWIM.

Comment: @dibansell12 have a look at the fiddle, the buttons are looking good. Probably in your HTML+CSS you have some extra rule that breaks the look of those buttons. Can you provide the entire css for your page? Anyway, instead of an image, please post a fiddle, is better for everybody to directly test what you are into. thanks

Comment: @dibansell12 remove `float: left` from `.rscontrol{..}`, example here http://jsfiddle.net/SWRaA/1/

Comment: Oh it works now !? after uploading to the webserver it decides to work Typical. Thanks lots! css is not my forte :)